# Can I buy a belt at ATL?

Tags: shopping, atl

I forgot my belt and have a sizeable layover at ATL, is there somewhere I could buy a belt?  None of the retail outlets have names I recognize as selling clothing or at least accessories.

Comment: I would wager that you could buy a belt at any major airport. Especially at the world's busiest airport, which is visited by more than a quarter of a million passengers every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly buy a belt airside at ATL.

Hartsfield-Jackson's website offers a [directory of retail concessions](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/concessions/), which includes pictures of most of the storefronts— you need not be familiar with the names; you can scroll through and find something that doesn't sound like a newsstand or electronics store and see from the picture or read from the blurb. For instance, the intro for [Brighton](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/concessions/view_stores.aspx?comp_id=327) mentions that it started out as a retailer for belts (I'm not sure if it is for men or women or both).

You will probably not find any deals, as the stores make their rent by charging "convenience prices" for travelers, and the clothing stores seem to be mostly upper-middle market. But there is probably at least one shop in each concourse with some kind of belt available, e.g. [Zegna](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/Passenger/Shop/view_stores.aspx?comp_id=56) on Concourse A, [Sean John](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/Passenger/Shop/view_stores.aspx?comp_id=114) on B, [Johnston & Murphy](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/concessions/view_stores.aspx?comp_id=407) on D, [Brooks Brothers](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/concessions/view_stores.aspx?comp_id=30) on E and in the Atrium, and [Tommy Hilfiger](http://www.atlanta-airport.com/Passenger/Shop/view_stores.aspx?comp_id=162) on F.

Comment: Cool, I did notice Tommy on the directory after I asked, but I was in terminal C then B and didn't want to go out to F.

Comment: @NickT It's very fast and easy to get between terminals at ATL.